# How to set soft focus effect for UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimage

My requirement is setting soft focus effect for UIImage in ios6.
soft focus effect is like below screenshot.

[image]

I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution. It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

Comment: That's...painful to see. You can probably create duplicate text fields one on top and below the original text, then give them a lower opacity . Do the say for the arrows. Not sure what's so nice about this but it's hurting my eyes. Or do you mean the soft blue glow next on top of the "select" tab? That's just a UIButton image state.

Comment: Maybe it is silly, but why not use a soft-focused special font if you need only statically this effect?  (in 1 min, i cannot found any on google..)